# etherscan kovan testnet didn't work?

Tags: etherscan, kovan

It seems that etherscan's kovan tesnet has some problems? 
the block of etherscan fell behind others!!
[image]

[image]

Is there another kovan testnet browser??

Comment: I don't see any issues with your screenshots. Maybe there was a fork of kovan